# "First Question" review "Test" biased

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Reporting a surprising review test.

Offered to review [thread_local + std::thread deadlock on destruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77126448/12846804), a question that looked all right except for a "pandas" tag that clearly did not seem to belong since the question is C++.

I go for "leave feedback" with suggestion to drop the tag in mind. In that process, I get the *STOP/Look/Don't worry we've handled the post* message. In the version now shown to me so that I learn something about reviewing, the pandas tag had disappeared.

... Surprise!

Please explain how I could have passed this test? Overlooking a misplaced tag surely does not seem like the way to go.

*Summarizing the answer since this is a duplicate from 2020: when filtering reviews by a tag, sometimes the system lies by faking my tag so it can submit me an extra test, and I should expect it's a test and I should guess it's a fake tag and ignore it.*
(That seems wrong.)

Comment: Ah, thank you, had not found that prior question. Summarizing: when filtering by a tag, sometimes the system lies by faking my tag and I should expect it's a test and I should know it's a lie. That seems wrong.

Comment: The audit is just to make sure you are paying attention, if you spot the fake tag then clearly you are paying attention and it has done its job.

Comment: You're looking at this from 10 years inplace. Nobody *new* knows that system-faked tags exist, until failing because of one. and looking up the meta site. What other traps do you have in store for me, as a 500-rep range noob?

Comment: "*What other traps do you have in store for me*" review audits, which have also bitten 10k-rep daily reviewers ;)

Comment: "*What other traps do you have in store for me, as a 500-rep range noob?*": Always open the Question/Answer (depending on which Queue you might be doing) also in a 2nd Tab, => a Qt/Answer with >+3 is (very probably) an Audit, a deleted Qt/Answer is (definitely!) an Audit.

Comment: Yes, I figured, beat a trick with a trick ^^. I can see this is no big deal compared to other issues since such a pyramidal system must be an ordeal to manage and balance. So that inconvenience will stay. Actually, I thought this was an area for AI. Design tests.

Comment: @AndrewT. sounds like you're talking from experience ;)

Comment: My personal belief is that the "STOP!" message is written the way it is to trigger exactly this... you being activated enough that you don't shrug it off, but instead you create a meta post. And from here whatever needs to happen can happen. Maybe the audit is pure BS and a mod can do something about it by changing the post state, maybe some education is necessary, whatever. As long as something happens. The audit system may be hugely flawed, but IMO that message is pure gold.

Comment: Wait until you get an audit based on a post that was deleted for a non-transparent reason like it being removed along with many of a user's other posts as part of a spam  or voting irregularity clean-up. Most of such posts are filtered out, but occasionally one slips through. Unless you have a history of being an ineffective reviewer, one-or-two missed audits isn't harmful.

Comment: And if you _are_ review-suspended for obviously bad audits like this, then we'll happy to lift the suspension upon request.